# How to quantify the specificity of a sample?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, accuracy

I would like to ask for direct tips or further reading how to evaluate the following data:

Here I am showing 55 violin-plots each representing a different protein. Each protein binds 50-5000 different genes and each gene can be bound 0% to 100% of times in a certain binding site.

Each violin-plot shows the distribution over all target-genes, so 50-5000 values of 0%-100%:

[image]

I noticed 2 phenomena:

1. The individual % are quite discrete. (what makes this difficult..)
2. The 55 distributions look very different

I would like to (somehow) quantify and potentially further visualize this point 2; the difference between the distributions. It seems like the proteins are quite specific in their preference for the site of interest: Either binding them a lot or never.

**My question is:** How can I evaluate the specificity of a protein?

I am asking to learn how you experienced statisticians would approach this! My intuition is to compare the individual distributions to a joined distribution (all 55 together), or to do an  analysis that leads to a statement like: To a probability >95% the chance of protein $x$ to bind the site is less than 8.3%. But I would like to learn the reputable way to doing this.

Comment: When designing a measure of specificity, it may help to describe what a high/low specificity protein looks like. Does a protein with high specificity bind to only one target 100% of the time? Or does it bind to many targets 100% of the time, and the rest 0% of the time? Is a protein that binds to only one target 50% of the time specific or not? How about one that binds to everything all the time? There can be lots of ways to calculate a measure of specificity, but what's most useful will depend on your application.

Comment: Yea, that's true! After a lot of thought I want specificity to reflect low entropy. I guess if the protein binds 100 genes I would compare the specific result to a randomized draw of 100 over the joined distribution of all gene-protein combinations.